# background color gets cut in smaller resolution

Tags: css, background, stretch

Hi I am having a problem stretching a background color. It fits larger resolution perfectly.
When the resolution goes below the width of 1254px, The background does not stretch. However the content inside the container remains perfect.

Heres the site. Kindly resize the browser below 1254px and check, you will find white space on the right side.

www.origininteractive.in/projects/stars11

heres the html code
view-source:http://www.origininteractive.in/projects/stars11/

heres the css code

http://www.origininteractive.in/projects/stars11/css/style.css

Thank you

Comment: which background color? i saw some blue background half of the page. But in bigger and smaller resolution it looks same. so which one you are talking?

Comment: The background color of blue will come till half of the page.I am having problem with the width of the blue color bg. Reduce the browser width to less than 1254px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that `main_body` & all it's *children* have static width, where header & footer container have `100% width`. width for `main_body` is `1237px`, thus when you resize below `1237px` top container get width of body but `main_body` container keep `width` of `1237px` thus a `scroll` is shown.

To get rid of this change all styles for `main_body` & it's *children* to percent based width,

OR give `body` a `min-width:1242px;` it will prevent `body` from going below `1242px`. (5px more cause some inner container is streching `main_body` to '1242px').

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block;` to your `body` and it will solve the issue.

Reason is, Most of your elements has hard coded width in `px`. example

```
.top_menu_header_cont {
width: 1237px;
height: 74px;
}
```

Because of this when width of your screen goes below 1200px, there is an issue of `display`.

Answer (score 0):

Apply min-width for inside container and inside footer.

```
 .inside_container { min-width: 1237px; height:830px; margin:0 auto;}
 .inside_footer { min-width:1237px; height:130px; margin:0 auto; }
```